# Swift, Another Way to Upload Pictures?

Tags: image, swift, uicollectionview

In swift, I am using a UI Collection view and plan on having around 100+ images in the collection view, and am not looking forward to copying those 100 images into the images.assets folder and having to put those 100 image names in the code. Is there a way to make the file path in the code to a folder on your computer? Or an easier way to upload a substantial amount of pictures, so it doesn't take long to write, as well as long to load when the user runs the app, or even crash!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the images.xcassets folder, simply select the "+" button and then select the "Import..." option.

[image]

From here, you can select all the images that you have named somewhere and if the images follow the @2x/@3x naming conventions they will be properly merged into the same image.

Comment: I saw how to just load them there, but if I am adding hundreds of photos, the only way to load the images is this way? And in the code actually write out the image name, so I could potentially be writing the names of 200 photos? I can't just make reference to the folder and thats it?